# Реализация функцию и построчную навигацию

Tags: php

Функция mb_substr($text, 0, 200, 'UTF8');

Покажет от 0 до 200 символы.
Мне нужно чтобы показал 200 слов а не символ.

Как такое реализовать?

И еще надо сделать построчную навигацию. В странице 200 слов.

Answer (score 1):

Если пробельные символы между словами не очень важны, можно посплиттить по ним и пагинировать по получившимся токенам:

```
class SplitPaginator implements IteratorAggregate {
  private $tokens = [];
  public $size = 5;
  public function __construct($text, $splitRegExp = '#\s+#u') {
      $this->tokens = preg_split($splitRegExp, $text);
  }    
  public function getPage($index) {
      $offset = $this->size * $index;
      return implode(' ', array_slice($this->tokens, $offset, $this->size));
  }
  public function getCount() {
      return ceil(count($this->tokens)/$this->size);
  }
  public function getIterator() {
      $n = $this->getCount();
      for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
          yield $i => $this->getPage($i);
      }
  }
}

$text = <<<'TEXT'
word1 word2 word3    word4       word5 word6 word7
 word8 word9 worda    wordb       wordc wordd worde
TEXT;
$paginator = new SplitPaginator($text);

foreach ($paginator as $i => $page) {
    echo "=== Page $i ===\n";
    echo "$page\n";
}
```

> ```
> === Page 0 ===
> word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
> === Page 1 ===
> word6 word7 word8 word9 worda
> === Page 2 ===
> wordb wordc wordd worde
> ```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ke6cg)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью регулярного выражения(preg_match_all) получить все слова/промежутки, а потом получить нужный срез слов.

```
function paginate($text, $page, $size) {
    preg_match_all('#(?<word>\S+)(?<space>\s+|$)#u', $text, $matched);
    $words = array_slice($matched['word'], $page*$size, $size, true);
    return trim(implode('', array_map(function($index)use($matched){
        return "{$matched['word'][$index]}{$matched['space'][$index]}";
    }, array_keys($words))));
}
$text = <<<'TEXT'
word1 word2 word3    word4       word5 word6 word7
 word8 word9 worda    wordb  Привет!     wordc wordd worde
 Пример Юникод слов
TEXT;

echo paginate($text, 2, 5);
```

> ```
> wordb  Привет!     wordc wordd worde
> ```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/DbEok)